# Excel: Comparing Times to get minutes apart

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get the + and - between two times but if the time I am subtracting from is greater than the time I am subtracting it gives me the difference in 24 hours.

[image]

I would like it to show this:

[image]

Perhaps this needs to be done in VBA. Have column B be the time to compare to and put max time apart as 12 hours, either positive or negative. So if the time is different by over 12 hours it becomes a negative instead of positive or vise-versa?

**@tysonwright** that is the best way to do it. Thanks. I assumed there was a better process but apparently there is not. So with that, I change the date to the next day to get 23:59 to 0:01.

Comment: There is no such thing as negative time on a worksheet. All you will receive is `#########`.

Comment: You must have a date component to the time, but only displaying the time.  If I do just time I get `#######`

Comment: Jeeped, by changing the advanced options of the workbook to "1904" it shows negatives.

Comment: Good point @BradleyRock. I don't usually work with 1904 dates.

Comment: Okay to revise my comment by changing the options to 1904, I get the `-00:01` when the date values has been removed.

Comment: this will work for this case: `=MOD(B2,1)-MOD(A2,1)` but will probably screw up other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your clockin is in A1 and your Schedule is in A2, your Difference should be:

```
=IF(A1>B1,TEXT((A1-B1),"-h:mm"),TEXT((B1-A1),"h:mm" ))
```